# TextView не показывает последние несколько символов

Tags: android, xml, textview

В `TextView` очень большой текст, который в одну строку не вмещается, и в некоторых местах последние несколько букв слова не отображаются полностью или частично, вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На устройстве отображается также. Как это победить?
Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HelpActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/help_text_title_main"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/help_text_title_1"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="0.5dp"
                android:text="@string/big_text"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ширину на match_parent пробовали менять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HelpActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/help_text_title_main"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="@string/help_text_title_1"
                android:textColor="#444444"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/big_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:ellipsize="end" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Если не нужна полоса прокрутки нужно в `ScrollView` включить `android:scrollbars="none"`

Comment: в третьем TextView ширину match_parent нужно использовать

Comment: Google не рекомендует использовать `match_parent`

Comment: кому и когда он рекомендовал это делать? здесь явно требуется ширина виджета на всю ширину родителя, было бы интересно посмотреть на рекомендацию гугла по этому поводу.

Comment: `You cannot use match_parent for any view in a ConstraintLayout. Instead use "match constraints" (0dp).` https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/.

Comment: это значит, что в ConstraintLayout вместо слова match_parent нужно указывать match_constraint, что соответствует значению 0dp, при этом смысл параметра остается прежним - занимать весь размер родителя. Об этом я и говорю, что размер нужен на всю ширину родителя, а не по содержимому виджета (wrap_content). Это не значит, что гугл не рекомендует использовать размер на всю ширину родителя, а значит, что обозначается он по другому

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить `layout_marginLeft="12dp"` на `paddingleft` у `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: А можно попробовать уйти от корневого Constraint заменив на Linnear

Comment: там в разметке нет боковых кострайнтов (привязки к краям экрана) и паддинги/маржины указывать смысла нет - им не на что "опираться"

Comment: @pavlofff, есть левый констрейнт `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`, а для пэддинга не нужны боковые констрейнты. Я проверил, если дать пэддинг, проблема уходит.

Comment: на скриншоте синего экрана явно видно, что правая сторона ушла за размер экрана, в таком состоянии можно ожидать чего угодно